# No message found under code 'user.title' for locale 'en_US'

Tags: java, spring, jsp, internationalization

having this error while trying to implement Spring i18n. I checked other post with same issues on Stackoverflow, none of them solved my issue...Any thought will be greatly appreciated!

Full error:

```
type Exception report

message javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'user.title' for locale 'en_US'.

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'user.title' for locale 'en_US'.
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:556)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:462)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


root cause 

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'user.title' for locale 'en_US'.
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:916)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:845)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


root cause 

javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'user.title' for locale 'en_US'.
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag.doEndTag(MessageTag.java:202)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_spring_005fmessage_005f0(index_jsp.java:124)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:83)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.64 logs.
```

Annotation based configuration:

```
@Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("WEB-INF/i18n/messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        CookieLocaleResolver resolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("en"));
        resolver.setCookieName("myLocaleCookie");
        resolver.setCookieMaxAge(4800);
        return resolver;
    }
```

messages_en_US.properties:

```
user.title= Fill User Form
user.name= Enter Name
user.age= Enter Age
user.submit= Submit
user.success= You have successfully submitted the form
```

index.jsp (for simple testing):

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/head.jsp"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>

<body>
    <h3> <spring:message code="user.title"/></h3>
</body>
```

screenshot to my project tree:
[image]

The resource bundle "messages" is under "WebContent/WEB-INF/i18n" and "MywebappConfig.java" is for configuration. Don't worry about the controller and other thing, since they are not even used in index.jsp.

I think this issue must happen in the configuration file where it sets the basename. Someone said using "/WEB-INF/i18n/messages" instead of "WEB-INF/i18n/messages" but it doesn't make difference. So.....any thought??

********EDIT**************

May be a good question to ask it where should I put my messages bundle?

Comment: try `messageSource.setBasename("i18n/messages");` ?

Comment: ResourceBundle names are effectively classpath locations, so when you build your project where does file end up in relation to your WEB-INF/classes ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Tried that, It doesn't work...Also, this is a Maven project, so I don't have the WEB-INF/classes folder. While it actually run successfully until I added i18n implementation...

Comment: Same issue is here may be it's help you. Please see this :-http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/67144-jsptagexception-no-message-found-under-code-title-for-locale-en-us

Comment: @sid i solved it from one of the comments. I move the i18n folder under src/main/resources and now it works fine. Thank you for your link! :)